# How to use JavaScript to control the behavior of a div across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, variables, events, listeners

I'm working on an HTML project where I have a retractable text box on each page, but I'm not sure how to implement the behavior I want.  Basically, some of the links will be part of a class that sets a variable, "NewRoom", to true when the link is clicked.  The other links will set "NewRoom" to false.  Once that's set up, I want the script to listen for three possible conditions:

If NewRoom === true, the text box starts extended

If NewRoom === false AND the text box is extended, the text box stays extended

If NewRoom === false AND the text box is retracted, the text box stays retracted.

Problem is, I'm not sure the best way to actually do this.  Any advice is welcomed.

Current javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ShowHideButton').click(function(){
    $('.MenuBar').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: For the 'next/previous page' his fully depends on the server-side possibilities you're using.

Comment: None, I'm afraid.  The whole thing is going to be cached and made available offline.

Comment: If it's for fully offline purposes you could choose to choose for localStorage to store the data

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that would do the logic for setting new room value and extending text box when a link is clicked.

```
var newroom = true;

function extendTextbox(val){
   //insert implementation for setting newroom val and extending texbox    
}

$(".classoflinkthatsetsfalse").click(function(){ extendTextbox(false):});

$(".classoflinkthatsetstrue").click(function(){ extendTextbox(true):});
```